# i cant enter number of times i can input name through keyboard, it skips the name entered

Tags: c, scanf

when i enter number of times i want enter names it skips the names that are to be entered.this prog only work if i enter number of time i want to enter names in the progam but not by input through scanf

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
int main()
{
    char name[100],*a,*s[5] ;
    int len,i,num;
    printf("how many names you want to enter ? : ");
    scanf("%d",&num);//PROBLEM : after entering num it skips the name i want to enter and prog ends
    for(i=0;i<num;i++)
    {
       printf("Enter a name : ");
       scanf("%[^\n]%*c",name);//becoz scanf can't take 2 words,space is taken as end of string 
       len = strlen(name);
       a = (char*) malloc (len+1);
       strcpy(a,name);
       s[i] = a;
    }
}
```

Comment: Many `scanf` formats skip leading white-space (like newlines from previous inputs), but `%c` and `%[]` do *not* skip leading white-space automatically. For those two formats you have to explicitly tell `scanf` to do it, but adding a single leading space in the format string. Don't use tricks like `%*c` to skip trailing space.

Comment: Always use `fgets()` (or `getchar()`/`fgetc()` for special occasions) for user input. Forget `scanf()` exists.

Comment: On another (but unrelated) note, there's really no need for the `a` variable. Instead you can use `s[i]` directly (as in `s[i] = malloc(...)` and `strcpy(s[i], name)`). Also, remember to add a check for `num` so you don't go out of bounds for the array `s`. And if you keep using `scanf` instead of using `fgets` as suggested by @pmg (and which I really recommend myself), then you need to clamp the input for `name` as well, to stop it from being written out of bounds.

Comment: And you really should always check what `scanf` (or `sscanf` if you need it) [*returns*](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/c/fscanf#Return_value).

Answer (score 1):

Consider what happens if the input stream is `5\nfoo`.  The first `scanf` consumes the `5` and converts the string to the integer 5, assigning it to `num`.  The newline character is next up in the stream, so `scanf("%[^\n]%*c",name);` consumes nothing, does not assign anything to `name`, and returns 0.  Since `name` was uninitialized, `strlen(name);` is undefined behavior, and there is no point in considering what happens after that.

To prevent this behavior, *always* check the return value of `scanf`.  If it returns 0 and does not assign any values, the program should handle that as invalid input.  Also, you probably want to skip the whitespace following the initial integer by using leading whitespace in the format string that you use to consume the names.

Answer (score 0):

Just add a blank in the format string like

```
scanf( " %[^\n]", name );
       ^^^
```

This allows to skip leading white space characters.

Or it would be even better to write

```
scanf( " %99[^\n]", name );
```

Pay attention to that you need to check that the entered value of `num` is not greater than 5 due to the declaration

```
char name[100],*a,*s[5] ;
                  ^^^^^
```

Also you should free all the allocated memory when it will not be required any more.

Another approach is to use everywhere in the program the function `fgets` and for entered integers to use the function `atoi` or `strtol` to convert a string to an integer.

For entered strings you should remove the new line character that can be appended by the call of `fgets`.

For example

```
fgets( name, sizeof( name ), stdin );
name[ strcspn( name, "\n" ) ] = '\0';
```